# How to get all the views of a particular database which are filtered by hard coded column value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get all views which are filtered by hardcoded date value for all views in a database. So, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT  
   v.name, m.definition    
FROM sys.views v
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = v.object_id
where m.definition like '%yourdate%';
```